# Correct way to use different signature to specific specialization of template method

Tags: c++, templates

Assume you have the following template method:

```
class A
{
    template<typename T>
    void f(const T& t)
    {
       // do something with t.
    }
};
```

Now, I want a different implementation of f() for a specific class other than T:

```
class A
{
    template<typename T>
    void f(const T& t)
    {
       // do something with t.
    }

    void f(const std::string& t)
    {
       // do something ELSE with t if T is std::string.
    }
};
```

I know I can use std::enable_if<> (some "disable_if" to be precise) on the template method, but I don't like that solution because than the template method "knows" about the other implementation.

Is there a better *more correct* way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you show is an overload, not a specialization. It should work as written: what problems do you have with it?

In any case, a specialization would look like this:

```
// Outside of the class definition:
template <>
inline void A::f<std::string>(const std::string& t) { ... }
```

Note that this specialization is no longer a template function, but a regular member function, just with a fancy name. So it should be declared in the header and defined in a source file, or else defined in the header with `inline` keyword (my example shows the latter).

Comment: You're right, I used overloading - sorry! In my case when I call f() with std::string the template implementation is being used instead of the std::string one.

Comment: You're right! I had missed something! :-(
Is one way better than the other? If I understand correctly they both lead to the same "binary" so there is no one better over the other. Do you agree?

Comment: Personally, I'd probably go with specialization because I feel it states the programmer's intent more clearly. Also, with overload, it's possible to call the generic version by using *template-id*: `a.f<std::string>(s);` or simply `a.f<>(s);` (either form precludes the non-template overload from being considered) - depending on the circumstances, this may or may not be desirable. For plain `a.f(s);`, there's no practical difference I could think of.